# Plotting unique values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame where the first column is time and the second is a letter:

```
Time                Letter 
2016-10-05 20:46:12 'A'
2016-10-05 20:47:12 'A'
2016-10-05 20:50:12 'B'
2016-10-06 00:46:12 'A'
2016-10-06 01:46:12 'B'
2016-10-06 01:47:12 'C'
2016-10-06 02:46:12 'D'
```

I need to group the data by hour and count number of unique letters per hour:

```
Time          Unique_values
2016-10-05 20 2
2016-10-06 00 1
2016-10-06 01 2
2016-10-06 00 1

df.groupby([df.index.date,df.index.hour]).Letter.nunique().plot(kind = 'bar', rot =0)
```

provides the plot with labels like (2016-10-05,7), (2016-10-05,8)...

Is there any way to remove the brackets and instead of 7, 8 etc. use 07:00:00, 08:00:00?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use pd.Grouper:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Time', freq='H'))['Letter'].nunique()
```

Or set the time column as index and resample:

```
df.set_index('Time').resample('H')['Letter'].nunique()
```

Both will fill the missing interval with zeros. Since you are plotting, I guess you'd want that. If not, you can assign the resulting Series to a variable and filter:

```
ser = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Time', freq='H'))['Letter'].nunique()
ser = ser[ser>0]
```

---

Due to a [bug](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/13453), nunique may not work correctly in the current version. A workaround supplied there by @jcrist is to use pd.Series.nunique with agg. So you can update the above code to:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Time', freq='H'))['Letter'].agg(pd.Series.nunique)
```

Or,

```
df.set_index('Time').resample('H')['Letter'].agg(pd.Series.nunique)
```

Comment: it looks like if in column `Time` are duplicates, you get wrong `nunique`. Or I am wrong? Please see my timings and can you explain me what can be problem (if there is some problem), because it is weird.

Comment: Thank you, I thought it is bug.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove minutes and seconds by converting column `Time` to `numpy array` by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html) and then `groupby`:

```
print (df.Time.values.astype('<M8[h]'))
['2016-10-05T20' '2016-10-05T20' '2016-10-05T20' '2016-10-06T00'
 '2016-10-06T01' '2016-10-06T01' '2016-10-06T02']


print (df.groupby([df.Time.values.astype('<M8[h]')])['Letter'].nunique())
2016-10-05 20:00:00    2
2016-10-06 00:00:00    1
2016-10-06 01:00:00    2
2016-10-06 02:00:00    1
Name: Letter, dtype: int64
```

**Timings**:

```
In [72]: %timeit (df.groupby([df.Time.values.astype('<M8[h]')])['Letter'].nunique())
100 loops, best of 3: 7.94 ms per loop

In [73]: %timeit (ayh1(df1))
1 loop, best of 3: 301 ms per loop

In [74]: %timeit (ayh2(df2))
1 loop, best of 3: 298 ms per loop
```

**Code**:

```
start = pd.to_datetime('2015-02-24 20:00:15')
rng = pd.date_range(start, periods=10000, freq='40T')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': rng, 
                    'Letter': np.random.choice(list(ascii_letters.upper()), (10000,))})  
print (df)

df1 = df.copy()
df2 = df.copy()

def ayh1(df):
    ser = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Time', freq='H'))['Letter'].agg(pd.Series.nunique)
    return ser[ser>0]

def ayh2(df):
    ser = df.set_index('Time').resample('H')['Letter'].agg(pd.Series.nunique)
    return ser[ser>0]

print (df.groupby([df.Time.values.astype('<M8[h]')])['Letter'].nunique())

print (ayh1(df1))
print (ayh2(df2))
```